# How to do string interpolation within a given context?

Tags: julia

Is there a macro `f` that allows to apply string interpolation within a given context?

`@f("abc$x", x=3) == "abc3"`

Or maybe a function `g`

`g("abc\$x", x=3)`

Answer (score 6):

You can introduce a new context with a `let` block. Here is a macro that does that:

```
macro f(s, args...)
    args = [:($(esc(a.args[1])) = $(esc(a.args[2]))) for a in args]
    quote
        let $(args...)
            $(esc(s))
        end
    end
end

z = 5
x = 1


@f("abc$x, $(2y), $z", x=3, y = 2x)
# "abc3, 12, 5"
```

Note the difference to a function, where `y = 2x` would refer to `x` in the scope of the caller, i.e., to `x=1`. So I'm not sure if this is what you need.